# tweepy It won't follow some of the tweets

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

seems like for some of the tweets with the keyword 'follow'
it will follow and for some of them it wont...
other than that it works fine(I didn't notice something else)
can someone pinpoint where is the problem?

```
class Listener():

def search(self, twts):
    global numoftwts
    for i in twts:
        names = ['follow', 'following']
        txt = i.text.lower()
        if not any(k in txt for k in keywords) or any(k in txt for k in bannedwords):
            continue
        if not self.is_user_bot_hunter(str(i.author.screen_name)):
            if not i.retweeted:
                try:
                    print("Trying to retweet status_id:{}".format(i.id))
                    res = api.retweet(i.id)
                    if res.retweeted:
                        api.create_favorite(i.id)
                        print('retweeted', numoftwts, 'times', '-',
                              str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')))

                        print(i.text)
                        print('\n')
                    else:
                        print("retweet failed")

                    if any(c in txt for c in names):
                        # print("Trying to follow something")
                        # if hasattr(i, 'retweeted_status'):
                        #     print("trying to fetch user_id")
                        user_id = i.retweeted_status.user.id_str
                        res = api.create_friendship(user_id)
                        res = api.get_user(user_id)
                        if res.following:
                            print("Successfully followed :{}".format(user_id))
                            print('\n')

                except Exception as e:
                    print("Exception:".format(str(e)))
                    continue
        sleep(600)

     def run(self):
            for eachkey in keywords:
            tweets = api.search(q=eachkey, result_type='mixed', lang='en')
            self.search(tweets)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        r = Listener()
        r.run()
```

where did I go wrong?

```
AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'retweeted_status'
> c:\users\x\desktop\twitterbot\twtbotcopy.py(64)search()
-> user_id = i.retweeted_status.user.id_str
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\x\desktop\twitterbot\twtbotcopy.py(70)search()
-> except Exception as e:
(Pdb) n
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic, you wrote : if the tweet has not been retweeted, get the RT user ID. Furthermore "if not i.retweeted" is not the good way to know if a tweet is a RT, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your getting any error where you are unable to get tweets from a particular user then use:

```
try:
    specific_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, tweet_mode='extended', q= <some query>, lang='en').items(500)
except tweepy.error.TweepError:
    pass
```

And if you want to access the retweeted attribute of a tweet then do this:

```
if hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status'):
            extracted_author = tweet.retweeted_status.user.screen_name
        else: extracted_author = tweet.user.screen_name
```

basically check whether `hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status')` of a tweet is true or not. It checks whether the tweet has the attribute named "retweeted_status"

Answer (score 0):

```
AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'retweeted_status'
-> user_id = i.retweeted_status.user.id_str
```

It means that you want to get the user ID of a retweet, for a tweet that is not a retweet.

I you want to know if a tweet is a RT, the test is :

```
if hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status'):
    # this tweet is a RT
```